# ObservableCollection Doesn't support AddRange method, so I get notified for each item added, besides what about INotifyCollectionChanging?

Tags: c#, vb.net, observablecollection, addrange, inotifycollectionchanged

I want to be able to add a range and get updated for the entire bulk.

I also want to be able to cancel the action before it's done (i.e. collection changing besides the 'changed').

---

Related Q
[Which .Net collection for adding multiple objects at once and getting notified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57020/which-net-collection-for-adding-multiple-objects-at-once-and-getting-notified)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

First of all, please **vote and comment** on the [API request](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/10752#issuecomment-359197102) on the .NET repo.

Here's my optimized version of the `ObservableRangeCollection` (optimized version of James Montemagno's [one](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/release-1.3.0/MvvmHelpers/ObservableRangeCollection.cs)).

It performs very fast and is meant to reuse existing elements when possible and avoid unnecessary events, or batching them into one, when possible.
The `ReplaceRange` method replaces/removes/adds the required elements by the appropriate indices and batches the possible events.

Tested on Xamarin.Forms UI with great results for very frequent updates to the large collection (5-7 updates per second).

Note:
Since **WPF** is not accustomed to work with range operations, it will throw a `NotSupportedException`, when using the `ObservableRangeCollection` from below in WPF UI-related work, such as binding it to a `ListBox` etc. (you can still use the `ObservableRangeCollection<T>` if not bound to UI).
However you can use the [`WpfObservableRangeCollection<T>`](https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/65ac9113e31d12e697cb58cd92601091#file-wpfobservablerangecollection-cs) workaround.
The real solution would be creating a `CollectionView` that knows how to deal with range operations, but I still didn't have the time to implement this.

**[RAW Code](https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/65ac9113e31d12e697cb58cd92601091)** - open as Raw, then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
// See the LICENSE file in the project root for more information.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Implementation of a dynamic data collection based on generic Collection&lt;T&gt;,
  /// implementing INotifyCollectionChanged to notify listeners
  /// when items get added, removed or the whole list is refreshed.
  /// </summary>
  public class ObservableRangeCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
  {
    //------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Private Fields
    //
    //------------------------------------------------------

    #region Private Fields    
    [NonSerialized]
    private DeferredEventsCollection _deferredEvents;
    #endregion Private Fields


    //------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Constructors
    //
    //------------------------------------------------------

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of ObservableCollection that is empty and has default initial capacity.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableRangeCollection() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection class that contains
    /// elements copied from the specified collection and has sufficient capacity
    /// to accommodate the number of elements copied.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection whose elements are copied to the new list.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The elements are copied onto the ObservableCollection in the
    /// same order they are read by the enumerator of the collection.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"> collection is a null reference </exception>
    public ObservableRangeCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection class
    /// that contains elements copied from the specified list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The list whose elements are copied to the new list.</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The elements are copied onto the ObservableCollection in the
    /// same order they are read by the enumerator of the list.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"> list is a null reference </exception>
    public ObservableRangeCollection(List<T> list) : base(list) { }

    #endregion Constructors

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Public Methods
    //
    //------------------------------------------------------

    #region Public Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">
    /// The collection whose elements should be added to the end of the <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/>.
    /// The collection itself cannot be null, but it can contain elements that are null, if type T is a reference type.
    /// </param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      InsertRange(Count, collection);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts the elements of a collection into the <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/> at the specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The zero-based index at which the new elements should be inserted.</param>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection whose elements should be inserted into the List<T>.
    /// The collection itself cannot be null, but it can contain elements that are null, if type T is a reference type.</param>                
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is not in the collection range.</exception>
    public void InsertRange(int index, IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      if (collection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));
      if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
      if (index > Count)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

      if (collection is ICollection<T> countable)
      {
        if (countable.Count == 0)
        {
          return;
        }
      }
      else if (!ContainsAny(collection))
      {
        return;
      }

      CheckReentrancy();

      //expand the following couple of lines when adding more constructors.
      var target = (List<T>)Items;
      target.InsertRange(index, collection);

      OnEssentialPropertiesChanged();

      if (!(collection is IList list))
        list = new List<T>(collection);

      OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, list, index));
    }


    /// <summary> 
    /// Removes the first occurence of each item in the specified collection from the <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">The items to remove.</param>        
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      if (collection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));

      if (Count == 0)
      {
        return;
      }
      else if (collection is ICollection<T> countable)
      {
        if (countable.Count == 0)
          return;
        else if (countable.Count == 1)
          using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = countable.GetEnumerator())
          {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            Remove(enumerator.Current);
            return;
          }
      }
      else if (!(ContainsAny(collection)))
      {
        return;
      }

      CheckReentrancy();

      var clusters = new Dictionary<int, List<T>>();
      var lastIndex = -1;
      List<T> lastCluster = null;
      foreach (T item in collection)
      {
        var index = IndexOf(item);
        if (index < 0)
        {
          continue;
        }

        Items.RemoveAt(index);

        if (lastIndex == index && lastCluster != null)
        {
          lastCluster.Add(item);
        }
        else
        {
          clusters[lastIndex = index] = lastCluster = new List<T> { item };
        }
      }

      OnEssentialPropertiesChanged();

      if (Count == 0)
        OnCollectionReset();
      else
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<T>> cluster in clusters)
          OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, cluster.Value, cluster.Key));

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Iterates over the collection and removes all items that satisfy the specified match.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>The complexity is O(n).</remarks>
    /// <param name="match"></param>
    /// <returns>Returns the number of elements that where </returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="match"/> is null.</exception>
    public int RemoveAll(Predicate<T> match)
    {
      return RemoveAll(0, Count, match);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Iterates over the specified range within the collection and removes all items that satisfy the specified match.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>The complexity is O(n).</remarks>
    /// <param name="index">The index of where to start performing the search.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of items to iterate on.</param>
    /// <param name="match"></param>
    /// <returns>Returns the number of elements that where </returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is out of range.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="count"/> is out of range.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="match"/> is null.</exception>
    public int RemoveAll(int index, int count, Predicate<T> match)
    {
      if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
      if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
      if (index + count > Count)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
      if (match == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(match));

      if (Count == 0)
        return 0;

      List<T> cluster = null;
      var clusterIndex = -1;
      var removedCount = 0;

      using (BlockReentrancy())
      using (DeferEvents())
      {
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++, index++)
        {
          T item = Items[index];
          if (match(item))
          {
            Items.RemoveAt(index);
            removedCount++;

            if (clusterIndex == index)
            {
              Debug.Assert(cluster != null);
              cluster.Add(item);
            }
            else
            {
              cluster = new List<T> { item };
              clusterIndex = index;
            }

            index--;
          }
          else if (clusterIndex > -1)
          {
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, cluster, clusterIndex));
            clusterIndex = -1;
            cluster = null;
          }
        }

        if (clusterIndex > -1)
          OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, cluster, clusterIndex));
      }

      if (removedCount > 0)
        OnEssentialPropertiesChanged();

      return removedCount;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a range of elements from the <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/>>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The zero-based starting index of the range of elements to remove.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of elements to remove.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">The specified range is exceeding the collection.</exception>
    public void RemoveRange(int index, int count)
    {
      if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
      if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
      if (index + count > Count)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

      if (count == 0)
        return;

      if (count == 1)
      {
        RemoveItem(index);
        return;
      }

      //Items will always be List<T>, see constructors
      var items = (List<T>)Items;
      List<T> removedItems = items.GetRange(index, count);

      CheckReentrancy();

      items.RemoveRange(index, count);

      OnEssentialPropertiesChanged();

      if (Count == 0)
        OnCollectionReset();
      else
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, removedItems, index));
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified collection,
    /// using the default <see cref="EqualityComparer{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>             
    /// <param name="collection">The items to fill the collection with, after clearing it.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    public void ReplaceRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      ReplaceRange(0, Count, collection, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified collection,
    /// using the specified comparer to skip equal items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">The items to fill the collection with, after clearing it.</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">An <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}"/> to be used
    /// to check whether an item in the same location already existed before,
    /// which in case it would not be added to the collection, and no event will be raised for it.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="comparer"/> is null.</exception>
    public void ReplaceRange(IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
      ReplaceRange(0, Count, collection, comparer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the specified range and inserts the specified collection,
    /// ignoring equal items (using <see cref="EqualityComparer{T}.Default"/>).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The index of where to start the replacement.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of items to be replaced.</param>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection to insert in that location.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is out of range.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="count"/> is out of range.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    public void ReplaceRange(int index, int count, IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      ReplaceRange(index, count, collection, EqualityComparer<T>.Default);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes the specified range and inserts the specified collection in its position, leaving equal items in equal positions intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="index">The index of where to start the replacement.</param>
    /// <param name="count">The number of items to be replaced.</param>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection to insert in that location.</param>
    /// <param name="comparer">The comparer to use when checking for equal items.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="index"/> is out of range.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException"><paramref name="count"/> is out of range.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="collection"/> is null.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="comparer"/> is null.</exception>
    public void ReplaceRange(int index, int count, IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
    {
      if (index < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
      if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(count));
      if (index + count > Count)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));

      if (collection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collection));
      if (comparer == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));

      if (collection is ICollection<T> countable)
      {
        if (countable.Count == 0)
        {
          RemoveRange(index, count);
          return;
        }
      }
      else if (!ContainsAny(collection))
      {
        RemoveRange(index, count);
        return;
      }

      if (index + count == 0)
      {
        InsertRange(0, collection);
        return;
      }

      if (!(collection is IList<T> list))
        list = new List<T>(collection);

      using (BlockReentrancy())
      using (DeferEvents())
      {
        var rangeCount = index + count;
        var addedCount = list.Count;

        var changesMade = false;
        List<T>
            newCluster = null,
            oldCluster = null;


        int i = index;
        for (; i < rangeCount && i - index < addedCount; i++)
        {
          //parallel position
          T old = this[i], @new = list[i - index];
          if (comparer.Equals(old, @new))
          {
            OnRangeReplaced(i, newCluster, oldCluster);
            continue;
          }
          else
          {
            Items[i] = @new;

            if (newCluster == null)
            {
              Debug.Assert(oldCluster == null);
              newCluster = new List<T> { @new };
              oldCluster = new List<T> { old };
            }
            else
            {
              newCluster.Add(@new);
              oldCluster.Add(old);
            }

            changesMade = true;
          }
        }

        OnRangeReplaced(i, newCluster, oldCluster);

        //exceeding position
        if (count != addedCount)
        {
          var items = (List<T>)Items;
          if (count > addedCount)
          {
            var removedCount = rangeCount - addedCount;
            T[] removed = new T[removedCount];
            items.CopyTo(i, removed, 0, removed.Length);
            items.RemoveRange(i, removedCount);
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, removed, i));
          }
          else
          {
            var k = i - index;
            T[] added = new T[addedCount - k];
            for (int j = k; j < addedCount; j++)
            {
              T @new = list[j];
              added[j - k] = @new;
            }
            items.InsertRange(i, added);
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, added, i));
          }

          OnEssentialPropertiesChanged();
        }
        else if (changesMade)
        {
          OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
        }
      }
    }

    #endregion Public Methods


    //------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Protected Methods
    //
    //------------------------------------------------------

    #region Protected Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by base class Collection&lt;T&gt; when the list is being cleared;
    /// raises a CollectionChanged event to any listeners.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void ClearItems()
    {
      if (Count == 0)
        return;

      CheckReentrancy();
      base.ClearItems();
      OnEssentialPropertiesChanged();
      OnCollectionReset();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by base class Collection&lt;T&gt; when an item is set in list;
    /// raises a CollectionChanged event to any listeners.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void SetItem(int index, T item)
    {
      if (Equals(this[index], item))
        return;

      CheckReentrancy();
      T originalItem = this[index];
      base.SetItem(index, item);

      OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
      OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, originalItem, item, index);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise CollectionChanged event to any listeners.
    /// Properties/methods modifying this ObservableCollection will raise
    /// a collection changed event through this virtual method.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// When overriding this method, either call its base implementation
    /// or call <see cref="BlockReentrancy"/> to guard against reentrant collection changes.
    /// </remarks>
    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      if (_deferredEvents != null)
      {
        _deferredEvents.Add(e);
        return;
      }
      base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
    }

    protected virtual IDisposable DeferEvents() => new DeferredEventsCollection(this);

    #endregion Protected Methods


    //------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Private Methods
    //
    //------------------------------------------------------

    #region Private Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper function to determine if a collection contains any elements.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collection">The collection to evaluate.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool ContainsAny(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
      using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        return enumerator.MoveNext();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to raise Count property and the Indexer property.
    /// </summary>
    private void OnEssentialPropertiesChanged()
    {
      OnPropertyChanged(EventArgsCache.CountPropertyChanged);
      OnIndexerPropertyChanged();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// /// Helper to raise a PropertyChanged event for the Indexer property
    /// /// </summary>
    private void OnIndexerPropertyChanged() =>
      OnPropertyChanged(EventArgsCache.IndexerPropertyChanged);

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to raise CollectionChanged event to any listeners
    /// </summary>
    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object oldItem, object newItem, int index) =>
      OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem, index));

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to raise CollectionChanged event with action == Reset to any listeners
    /// </summary>
    private void OnCollectionReset() =>
      OnCollectionChanged(EventArgsCache.ResetCollectionChanged);

    /// <summary>
    /// Helper to raise event for clustered action and clear cluster.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="followingItemIndex">The index of the item following the replacement block.</param>
    /// <param name="newCluster"></param>
    /// <param name="oldCluster"></param>
    //TODO should have really been a local method inside ReplaceRange(int index, int count, IEnumerable<T> collection, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer),
    //move when supported language version updated.
    private void OnRangeReplaced(int followingItemIndex, ICollection<T> newCluster, ICollection<T> oldCluster)
    {
      if (oldCluster == null || oldCluster.Count == 0)
      {
        Debug.Assert(newCluster == null || newCluster.Count == 0);
        return;
      }

      OnCollectionChanged(
          new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(
              NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace,
              new List<T>(newCluster),
              new List<T>(oldCluster),
              followingItemIndex - oldCluster.Count));

      oldCluster.Clear();
      newCluster.Clear();
    }

    #endregion Private Methods

    //------------------------------------------------------
    //
    //  Private Types
    //
    //------------------------------------------------------

    #region Private Types
    private sealed class DeferredEventsCollection : List<NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>, IDisposable
    {
      private readonly ObservableRangeCollection<T> _collection;
      public DeferredEventsCollection(ObservableRangeCollection<T> collection)
      {
        Debug.Assert(collection != null);
        Debug.Assert(collection._deferredEvents == null);
        _collection = collection;
        _collection._deferredEvents = this;
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
        _collection._deferredEvents = null;
        foreach (var args in this)
          _collection.OnCollectionChanged(args);
      }
    }

    #endregion Private Types

  }

  /// <remarks>
  /// To be kept outside <see cref="ObservableCollection{T}"/>, since otherwise, a new instance will be created for each generic type used.
  /// </remarks>
  internal static class EventArgsCache
  {
    internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs CountPropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count");
    internal static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs IndexerPropertyChanged = new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]");
    internal static readonly NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs ResetCollectionChanged = new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you help me with this code? Maybe I'm using wrong version of the framework, but for instance in line 48 in AddRange method there is "if (collection is ICollection<T> list)" - but what is this "list" object?

Comment: [C#7 pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#the-is-type-pattern-expression) mate.

Comment: Is it possible to use it in a WPF application? I'm trying to do so but getting the  “Range actions are not supported.” exception.

Comment: @Francisco It's under MIT, and if you're concerned, you found it on SO, so it's under [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), choose the one that does better to you :)

Comment: System.NotSupportedException: Range actions are not supported. dot net 4.5 vs 2017

Comment: @HenkaProgrammer I've updated my answer. In WPF use [this](https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/65ac9113e31d12e697cb58cd92601091#file-wpfobservablerangecollection-cs).

Comment: @lucas.mdo please see my preceding comment.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it wouldn't work on WPF as is? What is missing to make it work?

Comment: For people coming across the exception ''Added item does not appear at given index '0'" when using the AddRange method: A possible cause for that problem is passing a IEnumerable with a Linq Where() clause that causes items to be filtered out. This appears to mess with insertion. Use a ToList, ToArray, .. before passing your collection of items along to the AddRange method. This happened to me when I clear my collection and add a new range of objects.

Comment: It seems to be approved for API. What does that mean?

Comment: It means that someone of the community needs to find spare time and implement it and test it.

Comment: Seems there is a slight bug when using `IEnumerable` mentioned in the comments: https://gist.github.com/weitzhandler/65ac9113e31d12e697cb58cd92601091#gistcomment-2768966 there is a fix to call `ToList` on anything that uses it. mentioned in that comment

Comment: Amazing. This has fixed a big performance issue I had by adding hundreds of items to an ObservableCollection one by one

Answer (score 135):

Please refer to the [updated and optimized C# 7 version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45364074/75500). I didn't want to remove the VB.NET version so I just posted it in a separate answer.

### [Go to updated version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45364074/75500)

Seems it's not supported, I implemented by myself, FYI, hope it to be helpful:

I updated the VB version and from now on it raises an event before changing the collection so you can regret (useful when using with `DataGrid`, `ListView` and many more, that you can show an "Are you sure" confirmation to the user), **the updated VB version is in the bottom of this message**.

Please accept my apology that the screen is too narrow to contain my code, I don't like it either.

**VB.NET:**

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    Public Class ObservableRangeCollection(Of T) : Inherits System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T)

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the ObservableCollection(Of T).
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub AddRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
            For Each i In collection
                Items.Add(i)
            Next
            OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Removes the first occurence of each item in the specified collection from ObservableCollection(Of T).
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub RemoveRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
            For Each i In collection
                Items.Remove(i)
            Next

            OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified item.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub Replace(ByVal item As T)
            ReplaceRange(New T() {item})
        End Sub
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified collection.
        ''' </summary>
        Public Sub ReplaceRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
            Dim old = Items.ToList
            Items.Clear()
            For Each i In collection
                Items.Add(i)
            Next
            OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
        End Sub

        ''' <summary>
        ''' Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <remarks></remarks>
        Public Sub New()
            MyBase.New()
        End Sub
        ''' <summary>
        ''' Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class that contains elements copied from the specified collection.
        ''' </summary>
        ''' <param name="collection">collection: The collection from which the elements are copied.</param>
        ''' <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The collection parameter cannot be null.</exception>
        Public Sub New(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
            MyBase.New(collection)
        End Sub
    End Class   

End Namespace
```

**C#:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary> 
/// Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed. 
/// </summary> 
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam> 
public class ObservableRangeCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the ObservableCollection(Of T). 
    /// </summary> 
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

        foreach (var i in collection) Items.Add(i);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Removes the first occurence of each item in the specified collection from ObservableCollection(Of T). 
    /// </summary> 
    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

        foreach (var i in collection) Items.Remove(i);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified item. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void Replace(T item)
    {
        ReplaceRange(new T[] { item });
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified collection. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void ReplaceRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");

        Items.Clear();
        foreach (var i in collection) Items.Add(i);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class. 
    /// </summary> 
    public ObservableRangeCollection()
        : base() { }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class that contains elements copied from the specified collection. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="collection">collection: The collection from which the elements are copied.</param> 
    /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The collection parameter cannot be null.</exception> 
    public ObservableRangeCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        : base(collection) { }
}
```

### Update - Observable range collection with collection changing notification

```vb
Imports System.Collections.Specialized
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class ObservableRangeCollection(Of T) : Inherits ObservableCollection(Of T) : Implements INotifyCollectionChanging(Of T)
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Initializes a new instance of the System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(Of T) class that contains elements copied from the specified collection.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="collection">collection: The collection from which the elements are copied.</param>
    ''' <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">The collection parameter cannot be null.</exception>
    Public Sub New(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        MyBase.New(collection)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the ObservableCollection(Of T).
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub AddRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, collection)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        Dim index = Items.Count - 1
        For Each i In collection
            Items.Add(i)
        Next

        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, collection, index))
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Inserts the collection at specified index.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub InsertRange(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal Collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, Collection)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        For Each i In Collection
            Items.Insert(index, i)
        Next

        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Sub


    ''' <summary>
    ''' Removes the first occurence of each item in the specified collection from ObservableCollection(Of T).
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub RemoveRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, collection)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        For Each i In collection
            Items.Remove(i)
        Next

        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Sub



    ''' <summary>
    ''' Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified item.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Replace(ByVal item As T)
        ReplaceRange(New T() {item})
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Clears the current collection and replaces it with the specified collection.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub ReplaceRange(ByVal collection As IEnumerable(Of T))
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, Items)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        Items.Clear()
        For Each i In collection
            Items.Add(i)
        Next
        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset))
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub ClearItems()
        Dim e As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, Items)
        OnCollectionChanging(e)

        If e.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.ClearItems()
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub InsertItem(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal item As T)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item)
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.InsertItem(index, item)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub MoveItem(ByVal oldIndex As Integer, ByVal newIndex As Integer)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)()
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub RemoveItem(ByVal index As Integer)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, Items(index))
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.RemoveItem(index)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub SetItem(ByVal index As Integer, ByVal item As T)
        Dim ce As New NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, Items(index))
        OnCollectionChanging(ce)
        If ce.Cancel Then Exit Sub

        MyBase.SetItem(index, item)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnCollectionChanged(ByVal e As Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
        If e.NewItems IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each i As T In e.NewItems
                If TypeOf i Is INotifyPropertyChanged Then AddHandler DirectCast(i, INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged, AddressOf Item_PropertyChanged
            Next
        End If
        MyBase.OnCollectionChanged(e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Item_PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As T, ByVal e As ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
        OnCollectionChanged(New NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset, sender, IndexOf(sender)))
    End Sub

    Public Event CollectionChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T)) Implements INotifyCollectionChanging(Of T).CollectionChanging
    Protected Overridable Sub OnCollectionChanging(ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T))
        RaiseEvent CollectionChanging(Me, e)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Interface INotifyCollectionChanging(Of T)
    Event CollectionChanging(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T))
End Interface

Public Class NotifyCollectionChangingEventArgs(Of T) : Inherits CancelEventArgs

    Public Sub New()
        m_Action = NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move
        m_Items = New T() {}
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal action As NotifyCollectionChangedAction, ByVal item As T)
        m_Action = action
        m_Items = New T() {item}
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal action As NotifyCollectionChangedAction, ByVal items As IEnumerable(Of T))
        m_Action = action
        m_Items = items
    End Sub

    Private m_Action As NotifyCollectionChangedAction
    Public ReadOnly Property Action() As NotifyCollectionChangedAction
        Get
            Return m_Action
        End Get
    End Property

    Private m_Items As IList
    Public ReadOnly Property Items() As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Get
            Return m_Items
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Won't this still raise the individual collection changed events as you are iterating over the collection and adding/removing items?

Comment: Scott Dorman is correct. Calling the built-in Add method will trigger something like 3 events per add (a NotifyPropertyChange for item count, NotifyPropertyChange for item indexing[] and an NotifyCollectionChanged event for the item added). To get the best performance for a large update a complete replacement for ObservableCollection is required.

Comment: I do want to have these properties trigerred per add, I just don't want them to be triggered on each item.

Comment: @HiTechMagic Scott is not correct. because this calls Add on the protected Items IList<T> of Collection<T>, there are no such changed events sent, I have verified with unit tests counting the calls to the CollectionChanged event with AddRange and I can confirm is just one.

Comment: Need to call `OnPropertyChanged("Count");` and `OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");` in the add/remove/replace range methods to completely mimik the standard ObservableCollection.

Comment: @weston: What version of .Net did you test against?

Comment: @weston, I think these are called in `MyBase.OnCollectionChanged(e)`/`base.OnCollectionChanged(e)`, I haven't dealt with these classes for a long time, can you check it out and confirm?

Comment: @Shimmy My unit tests also confirmed I had to call these myself to behave like observable collection. But I got the idea from others comments and by decompiling ObservableCollection to see what a normal Add does.

Comment: @Shimmy, just posted unit test code as an answer, couldn't fit in comment.

Comment: C# code not working: Additional information: Range actions are not supported.

Comment: The C# code is broken, yes, but it's easy to fix. Just change all the `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.*` instances for `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset`, and don't pass a collection. My guess is that makes it re-evaluate the whole collection, but is basically just as good (and still much better than firing multiple notifications on every add). FYI: this made a load for me that was taking around 2 minutes take around a second, so many thanks!

Comment: Note that there are some issues with using the Reset event. Mouse clicks on the UI list items may be lost during the WPF update. See http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2013/02/22/batch-inotifycollectionchanged.

Comment: You may want to check the return value of `Items.Remove(i)` because if an item does not get removed, you don't want it to be enlisted in the change event.
Also, why not use `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add` and `NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove`?

Answer (score 35):

I think AddRange is better implemented like so:

```
public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (var i in collection) Items.Add(i);
    OnCollectionChanged(
        new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
}
```

It saves you a list copy. Also if you want to micro-optimise you could do adds for up to N items and if more than N items where added do a reset.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx

Comment: You spare a list-copy in your ObservableCollection, but lose the ability for fine-grained distinction in your consumer. If you consume the ObervableCollection yourself, you might be able to better optimize by being able to disinguish between "many items were added" and reset (which usually forces you to start from scratch)

Comment: @SamSaffron The link is dead.

Comment: The link @SamSaffron mentioned now is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/nathannesbit/addrange-and-observablecollection

Answer (score 14):

You will have to be careful binding the UI to your custom collection -- the Default CollectionView class only supports single notification of items.

Answer (score 13):

Proof of need for `OnPropertyChanged("Count")` and `OnPropertyChanged("Item[]")` calls in order to behave as per `ObservableCollection`. Note that I don't know what the consequences are if you don't bother!

Here is a test method that shows that there are two PropertyChange events for each add in a normal observable collection. One for `"Count"` and one for `"Item[]"`.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAddSinglesInOldObsevableCollection()
{
  int colChangedEvents = 0;
  int propChangedEvents = 0;
  var collection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
  collection.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { colChangedEvents++; };
  (collection as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => { propChangedEvents++; };
  collection.Add(new object());
  collection.Add(new object());
  collection.Add(new object());
  Assert.AreEqual(3, colChangedEvents);
  Assert.AreEqual(6, propChangedEvents);
}
```

@Shimmy , swap the standard for your collection and change to an add range and you will get zero PropertyChanges. Note that collection change does work fine, but not doing exactly what ObservableCollection does. So Test for shimmy collection looks like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestShimmyAddRange()
{
  int colChangedEvents = 0;
  int propChangedEvents = 0;
  var collection = new ShimmyObservableCollection<object>();
  collection.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { colChangedEvents++; };
  (collection as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => { propChangedEvents++; };
  collection.AddRange(new[]{
    new object(), new object(), new object(), new object()}); //4 objects at once
  Assert.AreEqual(1, colChangedEvents);  //great, just one!
  Assert.AreEqual(2, propChangedEvents); //fails, no events :(
}
```

FYI here is code from InsertItem (also called by Add) from ObservableCollection:

```
protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
{
  base.CheckReentrancy();
  base.InsertItem(index, item);
  base.OnPropertyChanged("Count");
  base.OnPropertyChanged("Item[]");
  base.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item, index);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As there might be a number of operations to do on an ObservableCollection for example Clear first then AddRange and then insert "All" item for a ComboBox I ended up with folowing solution:

```
public static class LinqExtensions
{
    public static ICollection<T> AddRange<T>(this ICollection<T> source, IEnumerable<T> addSource)
    {
        foreach(T item in addSource)
        {
            source.Add(item);
        }

        return source;
    }
}

public class ExtendedObservableCollection<T>: ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void Execute(Action<IList<T>> itemsAction)
    {
        itemsAction(Items);
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

And example how to use it:

```
MyDogs.Execute(items =>
{
    items.Clear();
    items.AddRange(Context.Dogs);
    items.Insert(0, new Dog { Id = 0, Name = "All Dogs" });
});
```

The Reset notification will be called only once after Execute is finished processing the underlying list.

Answer (score 3):

The C# summarized descendant.

More reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx

```
public sealed class ObservableCollectionEx<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    #region Ctor

    public ObservableCollectionEx()
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollectionEx(List<T> list) : base(list)
    {
    }

    public ObservableCollectionEx(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary> 
    /// Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the ObservableCollection(Of T). 
    /// </summary> 
    public void AddRange(
        IEnumerable<T> itemsToAdd,
        ECollectionChangeNotificationMode notificationMode = ECollectionChangeNotificationMode.Add)
    {
        if (itemsToAdd == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("itemsToAdd");
        }
        CheckReentrancy();

        if (notificationMode == ECollectionChangeNotificationMode.Reset)
        {
            foreach (var i in itemsToAdd)
            {
                Items.Add(i);
            }

            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));

            return;
        }

        int startIndex = Count;
        var changedItems = itemsToAdd is List<T> ? (List<T>) itemsToAdd : new List<T>(itemsToAdd);
        foreach (var i in changedItems)
        {
            Items.Add(i);
        }

        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, changedItems, startIndex));
    }

    public enum ECollectionChangeNotificationMode
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies that only a portion of data was changed and supplies the changed items (not supported by some elements,
        /// like CollectionView class).
        /// </summary>
        Add,

        /// <summary>
        /// Notifies that the entire collection was changed, does not supply the changed items (may be inneficient with large
        /// collections as requires the full update even if a small portion of items was added).
        /// </summary>
        Reset
    }
}
```

Comment: As the blog you linked to mentions, ListCollectionView (and probably others) do not support multi-item change events. You would have to use the Reset action instead of Add here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, adding your own Custom Observable Collection would be fair enough. Don't forget to raise appropriate events regardless whether it is used by UI for the moment or not ;) You will have to raise property change notification for "Item[]" property (required by WPF side and bound controls) as well as NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs with a set of items added (your range). 
I've did such things (as well as sorting support and some other stuff) and had no problems with both Presentation and Code Behind layers.

Answer (score 2):

this a simple observablecollection that notifies at the end of AddRange method, based on this post
https://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/

it is also asynchronous and modifiable across threads, based on this post https://thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/

```
public class ConcurrentObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    private bool _suppressNotification = false;

    public ConcurrentObservableCollection()
        : base()
    {
    }
    public ConcurrentObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection != null)
        {
            _suppressNotification = true;
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                this.Add(item);
            }
            _suppressNotification = false;

            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
    public void RemoveRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection != null)
        {
            _suppressNotification = true;
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                this.Remove(item);
            }
            _suppressNotification = false;

            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
        {
            // Execute the CollectionChanged event on the current thread
            RaiseCollectionChanged(e);
        }
        else
        {
            // Raises the CollectionChanged event on the creator thread
            _synchronizationContext.Send(RaiseCollectionChanged, e);
        }
    }
    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
        {
            // Execute the PropertyChanged event on the current thread
            RaisePropertyChanged(e);
        }
        else
        {
            // Raises the PropertyChanged event on the creator thread
            _synchronizationContext.Send(RaisePropertyChanged, e);
        }
    }

    private void RaiseCollectionChanged(object param)
    {
        // We are in the creator thread, call the base implementation directly
        if (!_suppressNotification)
            base.OnCollectionChanged((NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)param);
    }
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(object param)
    {
        // We are in the creator thread, call the base implementation directly
        base.OnPropertyChanged((PropertyChangedEventArgs)param);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MTObservableCollection.aspx?msg=3412002) is some additional help for collection changed and UI issues:

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link reference is a good resource  for a custom observable list implementation that supports the AddRange() and it is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableRangeCollection should pass a test like

```
[Test]
public void TestAddRangeWhileBoundToListCollectionView()
{
    int collectionChangedEventsCounter = 0;
    int propertyChangedEventsCounter = 0;
    var collection = new ObservableRangeCollection<object>();

    collection.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => { collectionChangedEventsCounter++; };
    (collection as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += (sender, e) => { propertyChangedEventsCounter++; };

    var list = new ListCollectionView(collection);

    collection.AddRange(new[] { new object(), new object(), new object(), new object() });

    Assert.AreEqual(4, collection.Count);
    Assert.AreEqual(1, collectionChangedEventsCounter);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, propertyChangedEventsCounter);
}
```

otherwise we get

```
System.NotSupportedException : Range actions are not supported.
```

while using with a control.

I do not see an ideal solution, but NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset instead of Add/Remove partially solve the problem. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx as was mentioned by net_prog

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification of the accepted answer to provide more functionality.

RangeCollection.cs:

```
public class RangeCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    #region Members

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a single item is added.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemAddedEventArgs<T>> ItemAdded;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a single item is inserted.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemInsertedEventArgs<T>> ItemInserted;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a single item is removed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemRemovedEventArgs<T>> ItemRemoved;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when a single item is replaced.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemReplacedEventArgs<T>> ItemReplaced;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when items are added to this.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemsAddedEventArgs<T>> ItemsAdded;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when items are removed from this.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemsRemovedEventArgs<T>> ItemsRemoved;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when items are replaced within this.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemsReplacedEventArgs<T>> ItemsReplaced;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when entire collection is cleared.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemsClearedEventArgs<T>> ItemsCleared;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when entire collection is replaced.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<CollectionReplacedEventArgs<T>> CollectionReplaced;

    #endregion

    #region Helper Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Throws exception if any of the specified objects are null.
    /// </summary>
    private void Check(params T[] Items)
    {
        foreach (T Item in Items)
        {
            if (Item == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Item cannot be null.");
            }
        }
    }

    private void Check(IEnumerable<T> Items)
    {
        if (Items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Items cannot be null.");
    }

    private void Check(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Items)
    {
        if (Items == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Items cannot be null.");
    }

    private void RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction Action)
    {
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    #endregion

    #region Bulk Methods

    /// <summary> 
    /// Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of this.
    /// </summary> 
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> NewItems)
    {
        this.Check(NewItems);
        foreach (var i in NewItems) this.Items.Add(i);
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        this.OnItemsAdded(new ItemsAddedEventArgs<T>(NewItems));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds variable IEnumerable<T> to this.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="List"></param>
    public void AddRange(params IEnumerable<T>[] NewItems)
    {
        this.Check(NewItems);
        foreach (IEnumerable<T> Items in NewItems) foreach (T Item in Items) this.Items.Add(Item);
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        //TO-DO: Raise OnItemsAdded with combined IEnumerable<T>.
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Removes the first occurence of each item in the specified collection. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void Remove(IEnumerable<T> OldItems)
    {
        this.Check(OldItems);
        foreach (var i in OldItems) Items.Remove(i);
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnItemsRemoved(new ItemsRemovedEventArgs<T>(OldItems));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes all occurences of each item in the specified collection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemsToRemove"></param>
    public void RemoveAll(IEnumerable<T> OldItems)
    {
        this.Check(OldItems);
        var set = new HashSet<T>(OldItems);
        var list = this as List<T>;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < this.Count) if (set.Contains(this[i])) this.RemoveAt(i); else i++;
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        OnItemsRemoved(new ItemsRemovedEventArgs<T>(OldItems));
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Replaces all occurences of a single item with specified item.
    /// </summary> 
    public void ReplaceAll(T Old, T New)
    {
        this.Check(Old, New);
        this.Replace(Old, New, false);
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        this.OnItemReplaced(new ItemReplacedEventArgs<T>(Old, New));
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Clears this and adds specified collection. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void ReplaceCollection(IEnumerable<T> NewItems, bool SupressEvent = false)
    {
        this.Check(NewItems);
        IEnumerable<T> OldItems = new List<T>(this.Items);
        this.Items.Clear();
        foreach (T Item in NewItems) this.Items.Add(Item);
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        this.OnReplaced(new CollectionReplacedEventArgs<T>(OldItems, NewItems));
    }

    private void Replace(T Old, T New, bool BreakFirst)
    {
        List<T> Cloned = new List<T>(this.Items);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (T Item in Cloned)
        {
            if (Item.Equals(Old))
            {
                this.Items.Remove(Item);
                this.Items.Insert(i, New);
                if (BreakFirst) break;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Replaces the first occurence of a single item with specified item.
    /// </summary> 
    public void Replace(T Old, T New)
    {
        this.Check(Old, New);
        this.Replace(Old, New, true);
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        this.OnItemReplaced(new ItemReplacedEventArgs<T>(Old, New));
    }

    #endregion

    #region  New Methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a single item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="Item"></param>
    public new void Remove(T Item)
    {
        this.Check(Item);
        base.Remove(Item);
        OnItemRemoved(new ItemRemovedEventArgs<T>(Item));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a single item at specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="i"></param>
    public new void RemoveAt(int i)
    {
        T OldItem = this.Items[i]; //This will throw first if null
        base.RemoveAt(i);
        OnItemRemoved(new ItemRemovedEventArgs<T>(OldItem));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Clears this.
    /// </summary>
    public new void Clear()
    {
        IEnumerable<T> OldItems = new List<T>(this.Items);
        this.Items.Clear();
        this.RaiseChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset);
        this.OnCleared(new ItemsClearedEventArgs<T>(OldItems));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a single item to end of this.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="t"></param>
    public new void Add(T Item)
    {
        this.Check(Item);
        base.Add(Item);
        this.OnItemAdded(new ItemAddedEventArgs<T>(Item));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Inserts a single item at specified index.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="i"></param>
    /// <param name="t"></param>
    public new void Insert(int i, T Item)
    {
        this.Check(Item);
        base.Insert(i, Item);
        this.OnItemInserted(new ItemInsertedEventArgs<T>(Item, i));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns list of T.ToString().
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public new IEnumerable<string> ToString()
    {
        foreach (T Item in this) yield return Item.ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Event Methods

    private void OnItemAdded(ItemAddedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemAdded != null) this.ItemAdded(this, new ItemAddedEventArgs<T>(i.NewItem));
    }

    private void OnItemInserted(ItemInsertedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemInserted != null) this.ItemInserted(this, new ItemInsertedEventArgs<T>(i.NewItem, i.Index));
    }

    private void OnItemRemoved(ItemRemovedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemRemoved != null) this.ItemRemoved(this, new ItemRemovedEventArgs<T>(i.OldItem));
    }

    private void OnItemReplaced(ItemReplacedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemReplaced != null) this.ItemReplaced(this, new ItemReplacedEventArgs<T>(i.OldItem, i.NewItem));
    }

    private void OnItemsAdded(ItemsAddedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemsAdded != null) this.ItemsAdded(this, new ItemsAddedEventArgs<T>(i.NewItems));
    }

    private void OnItemsRemoved(ItemsRemovedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemsRemoved != null) this.ItemsRemoved(this, new ItemsRemovedEventArgs<T>(i.OldItems));
    }

    private void OnItemsReplaced(ItemsReplacedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemsReplaced != null) this.ItemsReplaced(this, new ItemsReplacedEventArgs<T>(i.OldItems, i.NewItems));
    }

    private void OnCleared(ItemsClearedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.ItemsCleared != null) this.ItemsCleared(this, new ItemsClearedEventArgs<T>(i.OldItems));
    }

    private void OnReplaced(CollectionReplacedEventArgs<T> i)
    {
        if (this.CollectionReplaced != null) this.CollectionReplaced(this, new CollectionReplacedEventArgs<T>(i.OldItems, i.NewItems));
    }

    #endregion

    #region RangeCollection

    /// <summary> 
    /// Initializes a new instance. 
    /// </summary> 
    public RangeCollection() : base() { }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Initializes a new instance from specified enumerable. 
    /// </summary> 
    public RangeCollection(IEnumerable<T> Collection) : base(Collection) { }

    /// <summary> 
    /// Initializes a new instance from specified list.
    /// </summary> 
    public RangeCollection(List<T> List) : base(List) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance with variable T.
    /// </summary>
    public RangeCollection(params T[] Items) : base()
    {
        this.AddRange(Items);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance with variable enumerable.
    /// </summary>
    public RangeCollection(params IEnumerable<T>[] Items) : base()
    {
        this.AddRange(Items);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Events Classes:

```
public class CollectionReplacedEventArgs<T> : ReplacedEventArgs<T>
{
    public CollectionReplacedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> Old, IEnumerable<T> New) : base(Old, New) { }
}

public class ItemAddedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T NewItem;
    public ItemAddedEventArgs(T t)
    {
        this.NewItem = t;
    }
}

public class ItemInsertedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public int Index;
    public T NewItem;
    public ItemInsertedEventArgs(T t, int i)
    {
        this.NewItem = t;
        this.Index = i;
    }
}

public class ItemRemovedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T OldItem;
    public ItemRemovedEventArgs(T t)
    {
        this.OldItem = t;
    }
}

public class ItemReplacedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public T OldItem;
    public T NewItem;
    public ItemReplacedEventArgs(T Old, T New)
    {
        this.OldItem = Old;
        this.NewItem = New;
    }
}

public class ItemsAddedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public IEnumerable<T> NewItems;
    public ItemsAddedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> t)
    {
        this.NewItems = t;
    }
}

public class ItemsClearedEventArgs<T> : RemovedEventArgs<T>
{
    public ItemsClearedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> Old) : base(Old) { }
}

public class ItemsRemovedEventArgs<T> : RemovedEventArgs<T>
{
    public ItemsRemovedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> Old) : base(Old) { }
}

public class ItemsReplacedEventArgs<T> : ReplacedEventArgs<T>
{
    public ItemsReplacedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> Old, IEnumerable<T> New) : base(Old, New) { }
}

public class RemovedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public IEnumerable<T> OldItems;
    public RemovedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> Old)
    {
        this.OldItems = Old;
    }
}

public class ReplacedEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public IEnumerable<T> OldItems;
    public IEnumerable<T> NewItems;
    public ReplacedEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> Old, IEnumerable<T> New)
    {
        this.OldItems = Old;
        this.NewItems = New;
    }
}
```

Note: I did not manually raise `OnCollectionChanged` in the base methods because it appears only to be possible to create a `CollectionChangedEventArgs` using the `Reset` action. If you try to raise `OnCollectionChanged` using `Reset` for a single item change, your items control will appear to flicker, which is something you want to avoid.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use this code to extend ObservableCollection:

```
public static class ObservableCollectionExtend
{
    public static void AddRange<TSource>(this ObservableCollection<TSource> source, IEnumerable<TSource> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            source.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to change class in existing code.

Comment: This explains how C# extension methods work, but doesn't help with the main point of the question, which is how to add multiple items without getting multiple change notifications.