# Add elements from IList to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection

I have an ObservableCollection, and I'd like to set the content of an IList to this one. Now I could just create a new instance of the collection..:

```
public ObservableCollection<Bar> obs = new ObservableCollection<Bar>(); 
public void Foo(IList<Bar> list)
{
    obs = new ObservableCollection<Bar>(list); 
}
```

But how can I actually take the content of the IList and add it to my existing ObservableCollection? Do I have to loop over all elements, or is there a better way?

```
public void Foo(IList<Bar> list)
{
   foreach (var elm in list)
       obs.Add(elm); 
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> But how can I actually take the content of the IList and add it to my
> existing ObservableCollection? Do I have to loop over all elements, or
> is there a better way?

While there may be some "better" way which would involve using third party dependencies, some low level manipulation, etc. Simply looping over the collection is fine and works. I recommend doing that. In short—no, there is, effectively, no "better" way.

---

*This is the old version of this answer, which is a misuse of LINQ (potentially iterating the collection twice just to save a line or two of code). I wanted to delete the answer entirely, but I can't, since it's the accepted answer.*

You could do

```
public void Foo(IList<Bar> list) =>
    list.ToList().ForEach(obs.Add);
```

or as an extension method,

```
public static void AddRange<T>(
    this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items) =>
    items.ToList().ForEach(collection.Add);
```

Comment: Thx! Went with the ToList.ForEach approach for now. Will consider extension method if I need this more than one place..

Comment: The `Enumerable.ToList` extension method needlessly allocates a new `List<T>`. I'd probably recommend RaYell's answer.

Comment: @Richard - that is true although under the hood this does new List<T>(list) - which internally calls ((ICollection<T>)list).CopyTo(T[]) which in most implementations of IList<T> (e.g. List<T>) calls a native (external) array copy function. this should be quite efficient and only involve (at most) an atomic copy of the necessary references rather than iteration of members.

Comment: In Prism 4, it is CollectionExtensions.AddRange<T> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405741(v=pandp.40).aspx).

Comment: You can avoid the ToList(). I will execute 2 if you do it like this. The loop to convert to list and the one to add. Ilist inherits from Ienumerator so you can just `list.ForEach(obs.Add);`

Comment: @SergioEscudero no, you can't – https://dotnetfiddle.net/7nbPiK

Comment: That said, this (12 year old) answer is indeed a misuse of LINQ, so I'm going to edit it. I can't delete it, because it's the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

You could write your own extension method if you are using C#3+ to help you with that. This code has had some basic testing to ensure that it works:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> coll, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        coll.Add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Microsoft's [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) project for WPF includes a similar extension method (although, their version returns the collection, rather than `void`, to support method chaining).

Just reference Microsoft.Practices.Composite.dll and add `using Microsoft.Practices.Composite;`.

Comment: This will fire an event for each item you add. If you want to wait, and fire the notify at the end, you will need something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302933/how-to-avoid-firing-observablecollection-collectionchanged-multiple-times-when-r

Answer (score 1):

Looping is the only way, since there is no `AddRange` equivalent for `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an descendant to `ObservableCollection<T>` to add a message efficient `AddRange`, plus unit tests:

[ObservableCollection Doesn't support AddRange method, so I get notified for each item added, besides what about INotifyCollectionChanging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each)

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that solves this problem. It contains an ObservableList that can wrap a List. It can be used in the following way:

```
List<Bar> currentList = getMyList();
var obvList = new ObservableList<Bar>(currentList);
```

https://github.com/gsonnenf/Gstc.Collections.ObservableLists

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to instantiate an observable collection and want to add a new range into Observable collection you can follow the following method I have tried:

```
var list = new List<Utilities.T>();
            list.AddRange(order.ItemTransactions.ToShortTrans());
            list.AddRange(order.DealTransactions.ToShortTrans());
            ShortTransactions = new ObservableCollection<T>(list);
```

in this way you can add the range into ObservableCollection without looping.

Comment: You just cleared out all subscribers to the notify change event.