# Select data from local database

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, local-database

I'm trying to get my data that was stored in local database. I'm using for that something like this:

```
// Connect to the database and instantiate data context.
tablesDB = new TablesDataContext(TablesDataContext.DBConnectionString);    

// Define the query to gather all of the items.
var CategoriesTablesInDB = from CategoryItem todo in tablesDB.CategoriesTable
                                           select todo;

// Execute the query and place the results into a collection.
CategoriesTable = new ObservableCollection<CategoryItem>(CategoriesTablesInDB);
```

But my `CategoriesTable` have count = 0 after doing this, and `CategoriesTablesInDB` have it's sql query inside. I'm new to Windows Phone and I don't if it's the right way to do that. Is it something with my query is wrong, or I'm not doing it properly?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/2184212/1080742

Comment: @spajce sorry, but it's not what i'm asking about

Comment: yes. what i mean is you're trying to add items in `ObservableCollection` :)

Comment: @spajce Well... I'm not trying to add items exactly.. I don't have list or anything. I'm trying to execute query which return me items. So I don't think going through all the elements is possible.

Comment: I manage to solve that problem. Everything was right I just had empty database.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, can't help you with exact answer. But if you are just getting started you could also try store data in SQLite instead of native local database. It helps you build cross-platform applications in future and has a wide community support.