# How to use Combo Box AddRange in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, addrange

I have a little problem, I have an array and I want to add that in a Combobox, so I want to use the AddRange method, but it isn't available in WPF, is there a way that I can do it in the combobox?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it in a single statement, no.  You will have to loop over the array using foreach, adding each item individually.  Obviously you can encapsulate this in a helper or extension method if you plan to do this a lot.

If you're databinding the ComboBox.ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection (rather than manipulating ComboBox.Items directly), there is a trick you can use to avoid getting collection change notifications for each individual Add, described in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each).

Comment: Thanks for some odd reason it didn't click in my head, I used a while loop, going through the entries and then just outputting them. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't but you can use linq to simulate an AddRange

Try write something like that:

```
    ComboBox    combo;
    String[]    arrOperator = new String[] { "=", "<", "<=", ">", ">=", "<>" };

    combo = new ComboBox();
    arrOperator.ToList().ForEach(item => comboRetVal.Items.Add(item));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
 comboBox1.ItemsSource = array;
```

Comment: the OP explicitly states "I want to add" and not set otherwise this would work fine

Answer (score -5):

Try write something like that in codebehind :

> comboBox1.Items.AddRange(new[] { "Yellow", "DarkBlue", "Red", "Green" });

or

> ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
>   array.Add("1");
>   array.Add("2");
>   comboBox1.Items.AddRange(array);

Comment: There is no such method as AddRange, therefore I can not use it, but thanks anyway. I have found out how to do it.