# Adding a range of values to an ObservableCollection efficiently

Tags: c#, performance, collections, insert, observablecollection

I have an `ObservableCollection` of items that is bound to a list control in my view.

I have a situation where I need to add a chunk of values to the start of the collection. 
`Collection<T>.Insert` documentation specifies each insert as an O(n) operation, and each insert also generates a `CollectionChanged` notification.

Therefore I would ideally like to insert the whole range of items in one move, meaning only one shuffle of the underlying list, and hopefully one `CollectionChanged` notification (presumably a "reset").

`Collection<T>` does not expose any method for doing this. `List<T>` has `InsertRange()`, but `IList<T>`, that `Collection<T>` exposes via its `Items` property does not.

Is there any way at all to do this?

Comment: If you have a backing field for collection property - you can assign a new instance to it and then raise `OnPropertyChanged` for collection proeprty manually

Comment: related/possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each

Comment: +1 if `ObservableCollection` makes you think of quantum mechanics and the double-slit experiment.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nathannesbit/archive/2009/04/20/addrange-and-observablecollection.aspx

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The ObservableCollection exposes an protected `Items` property which is the underlying collection without the notification semantics. This means you can build a collection that does what you want by inheriting ObservableCollection:

```
class RangeEnabledObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void InsertRange(IEnumerable<T> items) 
    {
        this.CheckReentrancy();
        foreach(var item in items)
            this.Items.Add(item);
        this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
void Main()
{
    var collection = new RangeEnabledObservableCollection<int>();
    collection.CollectionChanged += (s,e) => Console.WriteLine("Collection changed");
    collection.InsertRange(Enumerable.Range(0,100));
    Console.WriteLine("Collection contains {0} items.", collection.Count);  
}
```

Comment: This other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302933/how-to-avoid-firing-observablecollection-collectionchanged-multiple-times-when-r) to a similar question suggested to add the following code to notify changes to the count and indexer properties: `this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));` 
`this.OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));`

Answer (score 11):

To make the above answer useful w/o deriving a new base class using reflection, here's an example:

```
public static void InsertRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
{
  var enumerable = items as List<T> ?? items.ToList();
  if (collection == null || items == null || !enumerable.Any())
  {
    return;
  }

  Type type = collection.GetType();

  type.InvokeMember("CheckReentrancy", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, collection, null);
  var itemsProp = type.BaseType.GetProperty("Items", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Instance);
  var privateItems = itemsProp.GetValue(collection) as IList<T>;
  foreach (var item in enumerable)
  {
    privateItems.Add(item);
  }

  type.InvokeMember("OnPropertyChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
    collection, new object[] { new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count") });

  type.InvokeMember("OnPropertyChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null,
    collection, new object[] { new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]") });

  type.InvokeMember("OnCollectionChanged", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, 
    collection, new object[]{ new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)});
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with inheritenance? Why are use using reflection instead of deriving a new class?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with inheritance, of course.  This is just an alternative to that.  

It may prove useful if you have a ton of legacy code and your serialization (binary) depends on an ObservableCollection type.  Easier and a far more pragmatic choice to just extend ObservableCollection in that case.

Comment: Hi @outbred . sorry but how do you "use" your example. Thanks

Comment: @NevilleDastur - use it like this:

var coll = new ObservableCollection();
coll.InsertRange(<some other huge list>);

It's an extension method so just make sure you are using the namespace where you declare the extension method and you should be good to go.

Comment: I voted for this as extension method allows me to use without having to change my collections to a new class.

Answer (score 4):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8607159/2934290) didn't show me the new entries in a DataGrid. This OnCollectionChanged works for me:

```
public class SilentObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        CheckReentrancy();

        int startIndex = Count;

        foreach (var item in enumerable)
            Items.Add(item);

        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, new List<T>(enumerable), startIndex));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count"));
        OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]"));
    }
}
```

Comment: These seem like the more appropriate change notifications.

Comment: For me, this resulted in an exception saying "Range actions are not supported", whereas the Reset one from the other answer worked. This was for populating a grid.

Answer (score 0):

10 years later, now that I've to use C# in my project and I don't wish to trigger multiple `OnCollectionChanged`. I've revised @outbred's answer into an Extension class.

Usage:

```
var stuff = new ObservableCollection<Stuff>() {...};
...
// will trigger only 1 OnCollectionChanged event
stuff.ReplaceCollection(newThings);

// equivalent without the extension methods
// stuff.Clear();       // triggers 1 OnCollectionChanged 
// foreach (var thing in newThings)
//    stuff.Add(thing); // triggers multiple OnCollectionChanged
```

The `ObservableCollectionExtensions.cs`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace System.Collections.ObjectModel
{
    public static class ObservableCollectionExtensions
    {
        private static BindingFlags ProtectedMember = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        private static BindingFlags ProtectedProperty = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

        /// <summary>
        /// Insert a collection without triggering OnCollectionChanged event 
        /// </summary>
        private static void InsertWithoutNotify<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items, int index = -1)
        {
            if (collection == null || items == null || !items.Any()) return;
            Type type = collection.GetType();

            type.InvokeMember("CheckReentrancy", ProtectedMember, null, collection, null);

            PropertyInfo itemsProp = type.BaseType.GetProperty("Items", ProtectedProperty);
            IList<T> protectedItems = itemsProp.GetValue(collection) as IList<T>;

            // Behave the same as Add if no index is being passed
            int start = index > -1 ? index : protectedItems.Count();
            int end = items.Count();
            for (int i = 0; i < end; i++)
            {
                protectedItems.Insert(start + i, items.ElementAt(i));
            }

            type.InvokeMember("OnPropertyChanged", ProtectedMember, null,
              collection, new object[] { new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Count") });

            type.InvokeMember("OnPropertyChanged", ProtectedMember, null,
              collection, new object[] { new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Item[]") });
        }

        public static void AddRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            if (collection == null || items == null || !items.Any()) return;

            Type type = collection.GetType();

            InsertWithoutNotify(collection, items);

            type.InvokeMember("OnCollectionChanged", ProtectedMember, null,
              collection, new object[] {
                  // Notify that we've added new items into the collection
                  new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
              });
        }

        public static void InsertRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, int index, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            if (collection == null || items == null || !items.Any()) return;

            Type type = collection.GetType();

            InsertWithoutNotify(collection, items, index);

            type.InvokeMember("OnCollectionChanged", ProtectedMember, null,
              collection, new object[] {
                  // Notify that we've added new items into the collection
                  new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
              });
        }

        public static void ReplaceCollection<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> collection, IEnumerable<T> items)
        {
            if (collection == null || items == null || !items.Any()) return;

            Type type = collection.GetType();

            // Clear the underlaying list items without triggering a change
            PropertyInfo itemsProp = type.BaseType.GetProperty("Items", ProtectedProperty);
            IList<T> protectedItems = itemsProp.GetValue(collection) as IList<T>;
            protectedItems.Clear();

            // Perform the actual update
            InsertWithoutNotify(collection, items);

            type.InvokeMember("OnCollectionChanged", ProtectedMember, null,
                collection, new object[] {
                    // Notify that we have replaced the entire collection
                    new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Example:
Desired steps 0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
--> min=0, max=100, steps=11

```
    static int min = 0;
    static int max = 100;
    static int steps = 11; 

    private ObservableCollection<string> restartDelayTimeList = new ObservableCollection<string> (
        Enumerable.Range(0, steps).Select(l1 => (min + (max - min) * ((double)l1 / (steps - 1))).ToString())
    );
```