# wpf improve performance binding huge observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have a problem of performance with an observable collection.
This foreach is binded with a combobox (MaAcquisition is an observable collection) :

```
 for (double i = 0.1; i <= 5; i += 0.1)
 {
     MaAcquisition.Add($"{i:0.0}");
     x++;
 }
```

With this foreach, every loop, I bind value to combobox, it's very slow.

So to improve this I do this :

```
List<String> MaAcquisitionList = new List<String>();
for (double i = 0.1; i <= 5; i += 0.1)
{
    MaAcquisitionList.Add($"{i:0.0}");
    x++;
}
MaAcquisition = MaAcquisitionList;
```

It's working but after this "foreach" I do a binding to choose the "selectedItem" =>

```
SelectedMa = MaAcquisition[x - 1];
```

Selected item is binded to my combobox and it's not working (the selected item is blank).

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MaAcquisition, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMa, Mode=TwoWay}"  IsEnabled="{Binding PreheatingDisable}"/>
```

And finally, there is the code for "SelectedMa" :

```
 public string SelectedMa
        {
            get { return _selectedMa; }
            set
            {
                _selectedMa= value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                RaisePropertyChanged();     
        }
```

Do you have an idea for this problem?

Thank's.

Comment: Can you show the code for the `SelectedMa` property/field?

Comment: You could take a look over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606994/adding-a-range-of-values-to-an-observablecollection-efficiently

Comment: SelectedMa should notify of changes. See for INotifyPropertyChanged examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About your `ObservableCollection` being slow:

Every time you add an item to `ObservableCollection`, the event `CollectionChanged` is rised that informs the views (in this case, this is a `ListCollectionView` that is generated when you bind to your `MaAcquisition`, that is in turn bound to your `ComboBox`) bound to this `ObservableCollection` that its `Items` has changed. (More details about that [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/05/itemscontrol-c-is-for-collection/))

To prevent this event being rised for every item when you add/replace a batch of elements, you'll have to, for example, extend the default `ObservableCollection` class. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303245/891715) it is explained how to do this.

About your `SelectedMa` not changing, are you sure you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged for the class that contains  this property and that you are rising it properly?