# MAUI - Enable dynamically-created button @ runtime from VM (thru Binding)

Tags: binding, maui

We have in VM a Submit button which executes some long-running code, like so:

```
[RelayCommand]
public async Task SubmitTravelOrder(int endWorkflowStageKey)
{
    string validationResult = ValidateData();
    if (validationResult.Length > 0)
    {
        await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(AppRes.ValidationNew, validationResult, "OK");
    }
    else
    {
        submitIsEnabled = false;

        ...... long running code .......

        if (response.Success)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Refresh");
            await Utils.Utils.ShowToast(SubmitButtonPopupMessage, Utils.Utils.ThisToastDuration.ToastDurationLong);
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(Pending)}", true);
            
            submitIsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            await Utils.Utils.ShowToast(response.ErrorMessage, Utils.Utils.ThisToastDuration.ToastDurationLong);
            //Just go back, no refresh required:
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Okay. Somebody noticed that if he clicks on the Submit button again while it is still executing, the submit will execute twice, thus creating duplicates in our repository.

So we thought that we should disable the Submit button while the code above hasn't finished. How to do this ? We have created in our VM this property:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private bool submitIsEnabled;
```

and the goal is to set this property as above: once the execution of the method starts, set it to false, and as it ends, set it back to true, so that the Submit button which would
be bound to the "submitIsEnabled" observable property gets disabled and enabled, respectively.

Problem is... we create the Submit button at runtime, in xaml.cs, in onAppearing, like so:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    Binding binding = new Binding("SubmitIsEnabled");
    binding.Source = viewModel;
    Button button = new()
    {
        Text = caption,
        ....
    };
    button.BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

but it doesn't work. How could we elegantly solve this, please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NET Maui Rebinding ItemsSource programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76502163/net-maui-rebinding-itemssource-programmatically)