# How to remove items from a Collection by using info from ICollectionView?

Tags: c#

I have a collection

```
ObservableCollection<PathInfo> _pathInfos = new ObservableCollection<PathInfo>();
```

and the corresponding sorted view:

```
  CollectionView _sortedPathInfos = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_pathInfos);
  _sortedPathInfos.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("LastAccess", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

Now I want to ensure that not more than _maxItems are in the source collection. The oldest items that exceed the max count shall be removed.
To achieve this I have to write quite many lines of code:

```
private void ensureCount()
{
  var removes = new List<PathInfo>();

  int count = 0;
  foreach (PathInfo info in _sortedPathInfos)
  {
    if (++count > _maxItems)
      removes.Add(info);
  }

  foreach (var remove in removes)
    _pathInfos.Remove(remove);
}
```

**Are there better (shorter) ways to do this?**

Answer (score 0):

LINQ can help you.

What about

```
_sortedPathInfos.View.Skip(_maxItems).ToList().ForEach(x => _pathInfos.Remove(x));
```

ObservableCollection does not support RemoveRange, and fires "element removed" event each time  you remove something from _pathInfos which is pretty inefficient in my opinion, when dealing with large lists.

[Why does ObservableCollection not support bulk changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9570800/why-does-observablecollection-not-support-bulk-changes) this thread has few potential fixes, in case you are interested.

Comment: Where do you find the `ObservableCollection.Remove` method which can remove an `IEnumerable<T>`?

Comment: That's why I said you might need to add .ToList(). You can always create your own extension method.

Comment: The point is there is not such a method `Remove` with such an overload. `Remove` accepts only an instance of type `T`, in this case it's `PathInfo`, not an instance of `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`. You don't even feel that it's wrong? Here is the link to the description for `ObservableCollection.Remove` method from MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. Changed my post. Thanks.

Comment: I tried your solution with a dependency to LINQ (using System.Linq;) but I get the error "CS1061" meaning that Skip() is not found as member of ICollectionView and no such extention method exists.

Comment: CollectionView has .View property that exposes sorted IEnumerable. I do believe if you just use _sortedPathInfos.View.Skip(...) then it should be fine. Updated my post with that.

Comment: OK, thanks. As I want to **keep** a specific number of items it should be `_sortedPathInfos.View.Take(_maxItems).ToList().ForEach(x => _pathInfos.Remove(x));` then.

Answer (score 0):

With LINQ you can use "Take" to get the desired amount of elements out of an enumeralbe:

```
_sortedPathInfos.Take(20);
```

Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: But Take() returns the result, it does not modify the source collection. So this is no solution. Or do I miss something?