# Best performance for ObservableCollection.AddRange

Tags: c#, mvvm, extension-methods, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I'm writing an extension method for ObservableCollection and have read that the .Add function raises 3 property changed events per call,

So that something like this is a bad idea:

```
public static void AddRange<T>(this ObservableCollection<T> oc, IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("collection"); }
    foreach (var i in collection) { oc.Add(i); }
}
```

Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: If you want to know the performance, measure it.

Comment: `Concat` does not modify `oc` so the second approach doesn't make sense.

Comment: To clarify what @BartoszKP wrote `Concat` is a linq method and does not modify the collection. It returns a new `IEnumerable<T>` that contains both `oc` and `collection`.

Comment: Thanks - I've edited my question removing the concat example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that `Concat<T>` is an extension method it is almost certainly just calling `.Add()` under the covers, it can't have internal knowledge of the class. You could use ildasm.exe to see what's going on for sure.

I hit performance issues for this very case using `ObervableCollection<T>` a few years ago.  The solution I eventually arrived at was to implement `IList<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` with a custom implementation that supports raising a single CollectionChanged event with an actual collection delta (instead of per-item events) in response to a call to `AddRange<T>`. Check out the documentation for NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs to get the details.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This looks like another great solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each