# AddRange ObservableCollection Issue

Tags: vb.net, performance, mvvm, observablecollection, inotifycollectionchanged

Hi I'm using this link to implement Fastest Observable Collection
[Best performance for ObservableCollection.AddRange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154291/best-performance-for-observablecollection-addrange.)

[ObservableCollection Doesn't support AddRange method, so I get notified for each item added, besides what about INotifyCollectionChanging?](http://ObservableCollection%20Doesn't%20support%20AddRange%20method,%20so%20I%20get%20notified%20for%20each%20item%20added,%20besides%20what%20about%20INotifyCollectionChanging?)

But on Calling AddRange() or ReplaceRange() methods multiple times, the performance gets slow, for example

```
AddRange() executed first time in 0.5 sec.
AddRange() executed 2nd Time in 1 sec.
AddRange() executed 3rd Time in 2.5 sec.
```

And it keep taking more time to execute methods even with same data.

For Better understanding, here is a code

```
For Each serie In SeriesList
serie.SeriesDisplayName = "New Series " +    newSeriesCounter.ToString()

 If newSeriesCounter = 1 Then
 serie.Items(1).Number = 500
 End If

 newSeriesCounter += 1
 Next

 Series.Clear()
 Series.AddRange(SeriesList)
```