# C# Can't add items to observable collection

Tags: c#, list, windows-phone, observablecollection, items

I have a problem where im trying to add my items to my observable collection, but i get this error:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'GameFinder.GetGamesList'

code:

```
private void RequestCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var gameData = feedXml.Root.Elements("Game").Select(x => new GetGamesList
            {
                ID = (int)x.Element("id"),
                GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
                ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
                Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform")
            })
              .ToList();
            Items.Add(gameData); // THE ERROR IS HERE - Items is the observablecollection
        }
    }

private ObservableCollection<GetGamesList> _Items = new ObservableCollection<GetGamesList>();
    public ObservableCollection<GetGamesList> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Items;
        }
    }

public class GetGamesList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You could also wrap your list in an ObservableList using an 3rd party ObservableList library. ( e.g. var obvList = new ObservableList(gameData); )

https://github.com/gsonnenf/Gstc.Collections.ObservableLists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
foreach (var item in gameData) Items.Add(item)
```

`gameData` is a `List<GetGamesList>` so you need to add each item from `gameData` into `Items` list and since `ObservableCollection` doesn't have `AddRange` you'll need to do it manually in the loop

Comment: Or see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each)

Comment: Thanks it works :). I would like to bind the oberservable collection Items to my LongListSelector, but its not working. In my xaml i do this: ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: Assuming that `DataContext` is fine I see no reason why that binding would not work

Comment: Im missing the DataContext.

Comment: i used it like this: this.DataContext = Items;

Comment: then change `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"` to `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` because `DataContext` is already `Items`

Comment: Can you tell me why i can't do the same thing with binding on a new page i navigate to on my app. I have another longlistselector on a new page i want to show data in too, but when i navigate to that page it doesn't show anything. Its the same thing i do except i use a new observablecollection for it. Any ideas?. Its a Windows Phone app.

Answer (score -2):

What exactly don't you understand on `cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'GameFinder.GetGamesList'`? Add method accepts single element, whereas you are passing in a list of elements. You can use `new ObservableCollection<GetGamesList>(gameData)`. And remove the `ToList` statement at the end of you Linq query.

Comment: Dear Vasek, welcome to SO and please read the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I understand the error message, but i was not sure how to solve it.