# How to convert the following foreach loop to linq format?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, foreach

Code:

```
foreach (var item in items)
  testItems.Add(new TestItem { Header = item.TestItemTypeName, Content = item });
```

`testItems` is of type `ObservableCollection<TabItem>`

How to convert the above foreach loop to linq format? Thanks.

Comment: Just being curious: why? Also what type is `testItems`?

Comment: Type is `ObservableCollection<TabItem>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
items.ForEach(i => testItems.Add(
    new TestItem
    {
        Header = i.TestItemTypeName,
        Content = i
    }));
```

Given that `items` is `ObservableCollection<TabItem>`

you could try

```
items.ToList().ForEach(i => testItems.Add(
new TestItem
{
    Header = i.TestItemTypeName,
    Content = i
}));
```

Comment: `.ForEach` is not listed in the intellisense.

Comment: Is the `items` a list, or an `Enumerable`?

Comment: `items` is an `IEnumerable`. Thanks.

Comment: You need to NuGet "Ix_Main" to get the `ForEach` operator for `IEnumerable<T>`. It's from the Microsoft Reactive Framework team.

Answer (score 1):

Providing that testItems has `AddRange` function, i.e. inherits from `List`:

```
testItems.AddRange(items.Select(item => new TestItem{ Header = item.TestItemTypeName, Content = item }));
```

As you have mentioned,this is an `ObservableCollection`, so the method is not available. In that case, the way you provided is the simplest possible. However, if you need to use this functionality more often, consider checking the following link:

[ObservableCollection Doesn't support AddRange method, so I get notified for each item added, besides what about INotifyCollectionChanging?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each)

Comment: `.AddRange` is not listed in the intellisense.

Comment: @JohnStephen I have improved the answer as per your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps:

```
var testItems = items
                   .Select(item => 
                       new TestItem {
                           Header = item.TestItemTypeName, 
                           Content = item
                       })
                    .ToList();
```