# How to convert List<Objects> to an ObservableRangeCollection

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I am using Xamarin Forms and their templates come with MvvMHelpers object to be used in the `ViewModel` as `ObservableRangeCollections`.  I know ObservableCollections.  If you try to do :

```cs
ObservableRangeCollection<Object> collection = new ObservableRangeCollection<Object>();
List<Object> objects = new List<Objects>();
collection.ReplaceRange(objects);
//error invalid type
```

Does anyone know how to use an `ObservableRangeCollection`? There is nothing on it in Google, Bing or StackOverflow.

Try the search you'll see Xamarin is promoting something so new that nobody knows what it is.

Comment: If i helped please mark my answer as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObservableRangeCollection is a helper class by the Xamarin Evangelist James Montemagno.

The source is available in his github: 
https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers

`ObservableRangeCollection` intends to help when adding/replacing `Collections` to a ObservableCollection.

In a "regular" ObservableCollection, for each new item added to the `Collection`, a `OnCollectionChanged` event would raise.

This is where `ObservableRangeCollection` gets in. It allows to replace/add elements to the Collection without firing an event for each element.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo! this explains a lot for me.  I see there is an answer from Sushi Hangover which also would be the right answer for me.  But your answer was first and adds some explanation that helps me understand which to choose. ObservableCollection versus ObservableRangeCollection and the events.

Answer (score 2):

`ObservableRangeCollection` is subclassed from `ObservableCollection`.

So in your example, substitute your `<T>`, i.e:

```
ObservableRangeCollection<string> collection = new ObservableRangeCollection<string>(); 
List<string> objects = new List<string>(); 
collection.ReplaceRange(objects);
```

Consult the code here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/master/MvvmHelpers/ObservableRangeCollection.cs

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was doing this but ReplaceRange threw an error each time. I know that its a Read Only class but when I switched to ObservableCollection the code worked.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that new. There's plenty of code using `ObservableCollection`.

What you are trying to achieve can be done like this:

```cs
List<Object> myList = new List<Objects>();

ObservableCollection<Object> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Object>(myList);
```

Read more about [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hi jzeferino, I use ObservableCollection for WPF but never used ObservableRangeCollection.  I didnt know it was an extension to the ObservableCollection. thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45364074/75500), which is an enhanced version of `ObservableRangeCollection` optimized for less event raising and reuse of items in UI.