# How expensive is data templating?

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, datatemplate

I have [performance problems](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38248842/1997232) and I am trying to dig the reasons.

So far I am not sure what is the problem and my next assumption it's data templating. Question: **how expensive is using data-templating**?

Lets see how expensive is single data template. Below is mcve.

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Item}">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" />

            ... we will add here more things to see difference
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
```

cs:

```
class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Property1 { get; set; } = "1";
    public string Property2 { get; set; } = "2";
    public string Property3 { get; set; } = "3";
    public string Property4 { get; set; } = "4";
    public string Property5 { get; set; } = "5";
}

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public object Content { get; set; } = new Item();
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

---

And here are some results (measured with VS profiler - application timeline in ms):

```
Test Nb Ni  Presenter    Items                         Bindings
A    1  1   2.42 (0.57)                                1.8
B    5  5   3.37 (1.15)                                1.8, 0.07, 0.1, 0.05, 0.08
C    5  10  3.63 (1.27)  0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.04, 0.04  1.7, 0.08, 0.05, 0.06, 0.05
D    0  1   3.38 (0.6)   2.7
```

Explanation:

- Nb - number of bindings;
- Ni - number of items (elements);
- Presenter - time of `ContentPresenter` (total/self);
- Items - items without binding times (when applicable);
- Bidings - items with bindings times (when applicable).
- A - is initial test, only one `TextBlock` with single `Text` binding.
- B - added 4 more `TextBlock` to bind `Text` to other properties.
- C - added 5 more `TextBlock` with static `Text="123"`.
- D - removed everything except 1 `TextBlock` with static text.

From what I can see, template itself takes `0.5 ms`. There is a big cost for creating first item (why???).

To be honest I am not sure in correctness of this method to measure performance. Therefore my question. Should I avoid data-templating and start using old [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) way of populating controls manually to gain performance or what?

Comment: Those close-votes: MCVE is here, copy/paste it and try. And it's not broad, you see my results, compare with yours and if they match explain them. 100 datatemplated very simple items (e.g. in `ListBox`) will take minimum `250 ms` to initialize. That's a lot. `ListView` with several columns - and you run into same problem as I do.

Comment: Half a millisecond seems pretty fast for template realization to me.  That's practically instantaneous to the human eye.  I'm not sure how much more of an improvement you can expect to get out of it.