# Why there is list of changes in observable collection event args?

Tags: c#, observablecollection, eventargs, inotifycollectionchanged

I'm trying to understand why there are two **list** properties `NewItems` and `OldItems` while you can only add or remove single item at a time?

```
private void InternalCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var changes = args.NewItems; // why this is a list?
}
```

I looked at available methods for `ObservableCollection` and I can only add or remove single item at a time.

if I can only add or remove single item at a time, what is the reason to have list of changes in event args and not a single add or remove change?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ObservableCollection<T>` is an implementation of `INotifyCollectionChanged` inteface and indeed it does not support adding or removing several items. But you can create your own collection class implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged` (and `INotifyPropertyChanged`) which will support adding or removing multiple items.

Comment: oh, I see. thanks for the answer. single change at a time sounds easier to manage. so basically I can write `NewItems[0]` instead of doing foreach.  I was worried maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

As an additional info to @Pavel's answer, `ObservableCollection<T>` does not support this out of the box, but you can create custom derived type of the `ObservableCollection<T>` that supports this. A great example is [`ObservableRangeCollection`](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers/blob/release-1.3.0/MvvmHelpers/ObservableRangeCollection.cs) from James Montemagno or a even more optimized version in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each).