# Add UI element from class outside of Page.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I have a rather odd question but I somehow hope that it is possible.
But after reading a lot I'm rather pessimistic about it.

That's why I'm asking the question here now.

I have some Lists/OberservableCollections that I create by reading from my serial port.
Now I have a debug screen in my app where I just display the content of those lists. 
So far so good. It's working nicely.

Now I have a settings/control page where I want to use the data to produce a control page. 
For that I need to use the different data streams in recieve and build controls for that.

The streams I get are as following:

1. Parameternames
2. Minimum and maximum values
3. Current values on device
4. In which unit the parameter is measured (if it has a definition for it)

I created a quick example on how I want it to look like:
[image: Example picture]

The first stream will be the first column of the view. The second stream is used to decide the minimum and maximum values of the slider or if I even need a slider or something else. Then I have the third stream to set the current values of the sliders/controls. and the last stream is used to add the unit description at the end of the row.

Is it possible to somehow create the controls after I read the streams without creating them in the code behind file?
I don't start the reading operations from my view so I can't use the code behind file directly. 
Maybe I can invoke a function in my code behind file from somewhere else?
Or should I implement an event for this? (never done that)

The only option I can think about is to create all the elements in the xaml and control their visibility with bindings but that would be totally unreasonable since I will have around 100 rows of parameters...

I'm really a bit helpless here :/

Best regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found an answer already...

While writing the question I remembered that it would be possible to use event handlers. So I looked up how to implement them.

I found an answer really fast but the ObservableCollection fires an avent everytime I add an element to it. I didn't want that since I would have 100 events...

So I found another post here on SO and implemented the extended version of an ObservableCollection.

It can be found [here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670577/observablecollection-doesnt-support-addrange-method-so-i-get-notified-for-each/45364074#45364074)

This extension implements an `AddRange` option. It just clears the collection and adds another collection into it. With this the `CollectionChanged`event only fires once and I'm happy :D